# Specify Correct method for animationListener in xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm getting a problem in AnimationListener :

1. The type name AnimationListener does not exist in type animation.
2. If I change to IAnimationListener also another error arises.

internal Animation.AnimationListener animationListener = new AnimatorHolder();

```
private class AnimatorHolder : Animation.AnimationListener {

    public int ChildCount { get; private set; }

    public AnimatorHolder() {
    }

    [Override()]
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    [Override()]
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (ChildCount > 1) {
            RemoveViewAt(0);
        }
    }

    [Override()]
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animation animation) {
    }

    [Override()]
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
}
```

And also getting error for `RemoveViewAt(0);`

Comment: Please, show the errors you're getting. The more info we have, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `Listener` classes exist only because it is how you program in Java and so the Xamarin team translated exactly it into C#.  They however have put all of these methods into the `Animation` class using the C# way of using events.

So, in your `Animation` class all you need to do is hook up to the events:

```
Animation MyAnimation = new Animation();
...
MyAnimation.AnimationEnd += (s,e) => {
    if (ChildCount > 1) {
        RemoveViewAt(0);
    }
}
```

See the docs at: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.Animations.Animation/